# Hibernate is looking for not existing DTYPE column in table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

For some reason Hibernate is looking for not existing **DTYPE** column in table. I wonder why? In my previous project everything is ok. But here i added class Freelancer in hierarchy and seems somehow it causes problem

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id2_6_0_,
        user0_.email as email3_6_0_,
        user0_.first_name as first_na4_6_0_,
        user0_.last_name as last_nam5_6_0_,
        user0_.login as login6_6_0_,
        user0_.password as password7_6_0_,
        user0_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_6_0_,
        roles1_.user_id as user_id1_5_1_,
        roles1_.role as role2_5_1_ 
    from
        users user0_ 
    left outer join
        user_roles roles1_ 
            on user0_.id=roles1_.user_id 
    where
        user0_.id=?
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column user0_.dtype does not exist
  Position: 197

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Hierarchy. Mapped super class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class BaseEntity implements Persistable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    protected Integer id;

    public BaseEntity() {
    }

//getters and setters
}
```

Than entity User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "role")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Set<Role> roles;

    public User(){}

//getters and setters
}
```

And I have Entity Freelancer

```
@Entity
public class Freelancer extends User {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "freelancer_skills",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "freelancer_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "skill_id")}
    )
    private Set<Skill> skills;

    public Freelancer(){}

//getters and setters
}
```

upd: Role class

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    USER,
    ADMIN,
    FREELANCER,
    CLIENT;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your role class.

Comment: I've added role class

Answer (score 0):

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Column(name = "role")
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

This looks weird here

```
@Column(name = "role")
```

since you are joining collection and trying to map to column?

edit:
I didn't read carefully. You should use some type of hibernate inheritance. Read http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/ . I think this could be a problem. Does Freelancer have it own separate table?

Comment: i don't think that it causes problem, because it works perfectly in previous project. Role is enum and is stored in DB as varchar - it works well

Answer (score 0):

I learnt that I should split my class hierarchy for Hibernate like that:

```
public class BaseUser extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "role")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Set<Role> roles;


    public BaseUser(){}
}
```

than i should extend BaseUser to create entity User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseUser {

public User(){}
}
```

and to create entity Freelancer:

```
@Entity
public class Freelancer extends BaseUser {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "freelancer_skills",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "freelancer_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "skill_id")}
    )
    private Set<Skill> skills;

    public Freelancer(){}
}
```

So it works ok now..

Answer (score 0):

That's because hibernate wants to specify the model type. In this case you have 2 models and 1 DB table.

You could (postgres example):

```
alter table users add dtype varchar(31) not null default 'Freelancer';
alter table users alter column dtype drop default ;
```

Then you can build and deploy.